# How to document only C functions in Doxygen?

Tags: c, doxygen

I want only C functions to get documented. However, there are also 
undocumented data structures and macros in the output. First I used

```
EXTRACT_ALL = YES
```

so it's clear. But when I switch that to

```
EXTRACT_ALL = NO
```

together with

```
HIDE_UNDOC_MEMBERS = YES
```

my output still contains undocumented functions and macros (although they are not shown as hyperlink). Can I get rid of that?

Comment: Did you have a look ath \cond and \endcond?